# How to disable Multi View like instagram on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, multiview

I have an online test application. so to avoid cheating, I want to make my application unable to use 'multi view'. as in the instagram application. how to do that on flutter framework?

[Can't use this app in Multi window view on Instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh5XN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

- **This can be done by adding simple one line in Manifest File**

*Add below line in AndroidManifest.xml file*

> **android:resizeableActivity="false"**

Now check your application it will work as you want.